# When printing X variable it prints "123" then the actual variable value

Tags: c++

When you type in 4 it should output only 2 but instead it outputs 12, same goes for 6 it outputs 123 and so on and so forth

```
int main() {
    int salary, yearsOfService, X; //rounded off for computation of bonuse
    string companyName;
    
    std::cin >> yearsOfService;
    
    if (yearsOfService >= 1){ //X is rounded off case number for amount of years
        X = 0;
        X = 1;
        std::cout << X;
        
        if (yearsOfService>=2){
            X = 0;
            X = 2;
            std::cout << X;
        }
        if (yearsOfService>=5){
            X = 0;
            X = 3;
            std::cout << X;
        }
        if (yearsOfService>=6){
            X = 0;
            X = 4;
            std::cout << X;
        }
        if (yearsOfService>=11){
            X = 0;  
            X = 5;
            std::cout << X;
        }
            
    }
}
```

Comment: `yearsOfService >= 1` and `yearsOfService >= 2` are both satisfied when `yearsOfService == 4`, so a result is printed in both cases.

Comment: The lines X=0 in the if's should be removed. End your matched conditions with "else if" not just "if"

Comment: This is what a debugger is for and if you don't know how to use it, this is a good opportunity to learn running your program one line at a time in a debugger, monitoring all variables and their values as they change and analysing your program's logic and execution. It should be possible for you to use your debugger to find all simple problems in this and all future programs you write, all by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program is doing exactly what you told it to do.  It will run down and execute those statements in sequence.  It sounds like what you're trying to do is this:

```
X = 0;
if (yearsOfService >= 11)
    X = 5;
else if (yearsOfService >= 6)
    X = 4;
else if (yearsOfService >= 5)
    X = 3;
else if (yearsOfService >= 2)
    X = 2;
else if (yearsOfService >= 1)
    X = 1;

if (X != 0) std::cout << X;
```

Another way instead of using `else` is to just add 1 to `X` any time one of these conditions is satisfied.  Then you can run them in any order.

Comment: And just for fun, something with less code repetition: https://godbolt.org/z/TYETfeM4M